# Filtering file names and sizes from line based text file?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with (read/write rules, author, file size, date, hours, minutes, file names with extensions)
And aiming to use regex to extract file names and size as well as date and hours minutes to a tuple with just these elements. 
File elements are:-

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164519 Dec 28 17:59 basics.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164477 Nov  5 19:21 basics.ipynb.orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  115587 Dec 11 11:50 bayes.ipynb
drwxr-xr-x 4 jttoivon hyad-all    4096 Nov 29 13:07 _build
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  198820 Dec 11 11:50 clustering.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    6647 Dec 11 12:20 conf.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   41828 Nov 28 13:26 example_figure2.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  125079 Nov 28 13:26 example_figure2.xcf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   24139 Nov 28 12:03 example_figure.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jttoivon hyad-all     650 Nov 28 12:03 example_figure.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   43632 Nov  2 22:05 exception_hierarchy.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   24366 Nov  2 21:26 exception_hierarchy.svg
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   72095 Oct  3 17:36 extra.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 1207075 Nov 28 16:02 face.png
```

I was aiming to find the right pattern to extract the file names yet since there are many formats which starts with a "." and an "_" and others who has two extentions. It's inconsistent and i couldn't find one pattern to extract them all

Here is my progress so far:

https://regex101.com/r/AoGD12/1

Extracted file size yet missing file names causing mismatches when tupling.

It was required to use just regex and not splitting.

Question:-
Write function file_listing that loads the file src/listing.txt. It should return a list of tuples (size, month, day, hour, minute, filename). Use regular expressions to do this (either match, search, findall, or finditer method).

Comment: Why are you trying to use regex instead of just splitting on whitespace?

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to [parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but if this is only a one-off thing, it's fine. These filenames are all safe and the output is consistent.

Comment: @wjandrea actually this is a course assignment and it is required to use regex

Comment: What about using `re.split(' +', ...)` to split on one or more spaces? Is that allowed?

Comment: Maybe to split the file to rows as part of the function

Comment: But using regex to extract the data

Comment: @Pitto no worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using regex?
Splitting on space is easy and perfectly fine for this use case.

Here's a simple and readable example for a Python novice:

```
import datetime

data = """-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164519 Dec 28 17:59 basics.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164477 Nov  5 19:21 basics.ipynb.orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  115587 Dec 11 11:50 bayes.ipynb
drwxr-xr-x 4 jttoivon hyad-all    4096 Nov 29 13:07 _build
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  198820 Dec 11 11:50 clustering.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all    6647 Dec 11 12:20 conf.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   41828 Nov 28 13:26 example_figure2.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  125079 Nov 28 13:26 example_figure2.xcf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   24139 Nov 28 12:03 example_figure.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jttoivon hyad-all     650 Nov 28 12:03 example_figure.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   43632 Nov  2 22:05 exception_hierarchy.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   24366 Nov  2 21:26 exception_hierarchy.svg
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   72095 Oct  3 17:36 extra.ipynb
-rw------- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 1207075 Nov 28 16:02 face.png"""

rows = data.split("\n")
new_rows = []

for row in rows:
    row_data = row.split()
    mode = row_data[0]
    hardlink_count = row_data[1]
    user = row_data[2]
    group = row_data[3]
    size = row_data[4]
    month = row_data[5]
    day = row_data[6]
    hour = row_data[7]
    filename = row_data[8]
    # Also doable in a single line in Python 3 with:
    # mode, hardlink_count, user, group, size, month, day, time, *filename = row.split()
    new_rows.append((filename, size, month, day, hour))
    # You can use something similar if you need to transform the string date
    # into a date object:
    #new_rows.append((filename, size, datetime.datetime.strptime("{}-{} {}".format(month, day, hour), '%b-%d %H:%M')))

print(new_rows)
```

Here's a shorter version, a bit more pythonic:

```
new_rows = [(row.split()[8], row.split()[4],
             datetime.datetime.strptime("{}-{} {}".format(row.split()[5], row.split()[6],
                                                          row.split()[7]),
                                        '%b-%d %H:%M')) for row in data.split("\n")]
print(new_rows)
```

**Edit**
Here's a RegEx solution too:

```
extracted_data = re.findall('^(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+', data, re.MULTILINE)
print(extracted_data)
```

**Output**

```
[('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '164519', 'Dec', '28', '17:59', 'basics.ipynb'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '164477', 'Nov', '5', '19:21', 'basics.ipynb.orig'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '115587', 'Dec', '11', '11:50', 'bayes.ipynb'), ('drwxr-xr-x', '4', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '4096', 'Nov', '29', '13:07', '_build'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '198820', 'Dec', '11', '11:50', 'clustering.ipynb'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '6647', 'Dec', '11', '12:20', 'conf.py'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '41828', 'Nov', '28', '13:26', 'example_figure2.png'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '125079', 'Nov', '28', '13:26', 'example_figure2.xcf'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '24139', 'Nov', '28', '12:03', 'example_figure.png'), ('-rwxr-xr-x', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '650', 'Nov', '28', '12:03', 'example_figure.py'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '25399', 'Nov', '2', '21:25', 'exception_hierarchy.pdf'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '43632', 'Nov', '2', '22:05', 'exception_hierarchy.png'), ('-rw-r--r--', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '24366', 'Nov', '2', '21:26', 'exception_hierarchy.svg'), ('-rw-------', '1', 'jttoivon', 'hyad-all', '72095', 'Oct', '3', '17:36', 'extra.ipynb')]
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough for the swift reply. Yet this js an assignment on an online course self learning so it is required to use regex

Comment: I see your point, @OmarAhmed!
I will also prepare a RegEx one (as soon as my baby is sleeping :D)

Comment: So you mapped the groups that are separated with a space or more to the created list as tuples?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! The list containing tuples is automatically created by re.findall()

Comment: Oh that's much simpler i was going for an approach of using regex for each type of attribute to extract then combining them in a tuple. Thank you this is much much simpler

Comment: Your approach is more precise but in this case we're parsing a text that basically has spaces as column delimiters so my approach - even if a bit sloppier as a general idea - fits the bill.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for kindly explaining and excusing my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `pathlib.Path.stat` and `os.stat`.

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(".").iterdir():
    print(path.stat())
```

Comment: AFAIR he has a text file... Not sure if the text file can be generated at his/her will (in other words if he/she has access to the server / pc or not).

Answer (score 0):

Try this... `content.txt` which is the text file

```
details=[]

with open('content.txt') as f:
    for r in f.readlines():
        _, _, _, _, file_size, month, date, time, file_name  = r.split(maxsplit=9)
        record = (file_size, month, date, time, file_name)
        details.append(record)

print(details)
```